# OfficeJS and VueRouter do not work together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, office-js

I am on the way of creating a very simple Add-in with [Office.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-vue#update-the-app). I chose [Vue](https://vuejs.org) and [Vue Router 4](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) to create the frontend of my Add-in. The following code was taken from the vue router guide and it work as long as I do not include Office.js lib:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js">
```

As long as I include `office.js` into the mix, this is what I received in Chrome dev console and Vue Router no longer works:

many of this:

```
[Vue Router warn]: Error with push/replace State TypeError: history[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:514:62)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
```

and one of this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
    at replace (vue-router@4:529:11)
    at popStateHandler (vue-router@4:405:15)
    at changeLocation (vue-router@4:522:55)
```

This code will reproduce this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>
    </p>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
  <!-- include office.js make vue-router not working -->
  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>

  <script>
    const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
    const About = { template: '<div>About</div>' }

    const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
      history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
      routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/about', component: About },
      ]
    })

    const app = Vue.createApp({})
    app.use(router)
    app.mount('#app')
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What I can find on the internet now is a [workaround](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3154):

Insert the followings before importing vue router and init it.

```
delete window.history.pushState; // workaround to make sure vue router doesn't try using pushState
delete window.history.replaceState; // workaround to make sure vue router doesn't try using replaceState
```

Comment: Does the workaround work?

Comment: Yes, I tested and it works

Answer (score 2):

I found that using `VueRouter.createMemoryHistory()` gets around this issue.